# How to show an alternate data processing inequality concerning KL divergence between conditionals?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, information-theory, kullback-leibler, mutual-information

Suppose $(Y,X) \sim F \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R^d})}$. Consider an arbitrary transformation $f$ that acts on $X$. My intuition is that the following should be a result in information theory:

$$
\mathbb{E}_X KL\big( Y|X, Y|f(X) \big) \leq \mathbb{E}_X KL\big( Y|X, Y \big)= MI(Y,X).
$$,

However, I haven't been able to show this. Is my intuition wrong? Any thoughts on how to show it if it is true?

Comment: I think you need to define arbitrary transformation first. This is not possible to prove anything in this setting. First we are not even sure the expression at the left of your inequality is defined (if f dosnt have some condition).

Comment: Are there really any interesting examples where the expression on the left doesn't exists? The density exists in the transformed space if $f$ is measurable...